# How to move the right div to the right with css

Tags: html, css

Here is a simple box with two columns:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="image-title">Image title
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </div><!-- left -->
  <div class="right">
    <div class="title">
     <h2>Title here</h2>
    </div><!-- title -->
    <div class="content">
     <p>Content here.</p>
     <p>Content here.</p>
    </div><!-- content -->
  </div><!-- right -->
</div><!-- wrapper -->
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 1px;
}
.left {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
   text-align: center;
}
.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r0by9cLw/2/)

I expected that the right div should be placed on the right side, but it's placed under the left div element. How can I make it done?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [I am too sleepy to post a nice answer](http://jsfiddle.net/r0by9cLw/8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really easy to do.
Just use float: right;

```
.right {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 70%;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I modified also the width to be less than 70%. Is it because the padding value?

Comment: no, is not because the padding but because of border. your div are 30% + 2pixel and 70% + 2 pixel

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any way to make the height of the left div and that of the right div identical?

Comment: yes there is, for do that personally i am use jquery. i get the height dimensions of both div, something like this: var div1 = $('#myDiv1').height() and var div2 = $('#myDiv2').height(), then i am check which one is bigger and i put to the little one the height of the other one, for example: $('#myDiv1').css({'height': div2})

Answer (score 2):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` to align it perfectly. No need to use `align:right;` or adjusted width.

```css
#wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 1px;
}
.left {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="image-title">Image title
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </div><!-- left -->
  <div class="right">
    <div class="title">
     <h2>Title here</h2>
    </div><!-- title -->
    <div class="content">
     <p>Content here.</p>
     <p>Content here.</p>
    </div><!-- content -->
  </div><!-- right -->
</div><!-- wrapper -->
```

Comment: It's awesome. Thank you very much^^

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want. But if you want the .right div to be on the right side then you need to apply

```
float:right
```

[See the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/r0by9cLw/6/).

Also you have a border of 1px outside the box. It needs to be inside you could use box-shadow.

```
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px gray;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px gray;
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px gray;
```

[See the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/r0by9cLw/11/).

Update: You have no height on the divs, so the height is being established by your text. Simply apply a height.

```
.left {
    height:130px;

.right {
    height:130px;
```

[See the example here](http://jsfiddle.net/r0by9cLw/29/).

Comment: Thank you very much, Kadeem. Is it possible to adjust the height of the left div to match the height of the right div?

Comment: Please vote up correct answer for future users. and not worries Peter.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue here is that you're adding 3px as borders. These aren't counted into the % when you measure the width, which makes the inner divs too wide to fit on one line. if you add the following line to the `right` div you will see what I mean:

```
.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    float: right;
}
```

Now we've fixed the second issue; the div will now float to the right as intended, but you can see the boxes are cutting each other's edges. Nowadays there's a nice trick to fix that, and that is `box-sizing: border-box;` which will automatically match the borders as your div's edge, not outside of it as the standard does.

```css
#wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 1px;
}
.left {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
   text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    float: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="image-title">Image title
    </div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </div><!-- left -->
  <div class="right">
    <div class="title">
     <h2>Title here</h2>
    </div><!-- title -->
    <div class="content">
     <p>Content here.</p>
     <p>Content here.</p>
    </div><!-- content -->
  </div><!-- right -->
</div><!-- wrapper -->
```

Comment: What if I add margin to "right"? Do I need to reduce the width (e.g. from "70%" to "65%" or something)? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, adding margin is adding space outside of the box, which will eat from the space the two divs share "overflowing" the row, ex; total width is 100px, margin is 1px and div is 50px, then the div's total width is 51px.

Answer (score 0):

To the `right` div to be on the right, you need to add `float:right` to the css:

```
.right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    float:right;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r0by9cLw/5/)

Answer (score 0):

A minimized css file for this could look like this.

```
#wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 1px;
}
.left, .right {
    height:130px;
    display: inline-block;
/* choose your border method
    border: 1px solid grey;
Or
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px gray;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px gray;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px gray;
*/
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 70%;
}
```